# Crystal Report displaying formula result as 00

Tags: crystal-reports-2010

First of all I would like to apologize if this has been asked before, I just couldn't find the answer.
To the point:
My problem is as follows: I am using Crystal Reports for VS2010 and I have a field that should dispaly 1 or -1 based on an If check

```
If IsNull ({Orders.OrderReplacedBy})
Then 1
Else -1
```

It should display in my report 1 for null values of the field and -1 otherwise. Problem is that in my report I get only .00 no matter the value of the if test.
Furthermore I have another formula field that does of a sum of all the 1s and -1s showed on the report, and it seems to be working a little weird. In my database I have 772 total rows, of which 39 are NULL (so there should be 733 1s and 39 -1s with a sum of 694) and the displayed sum is 488. The code for the sum is as follows:

```
Sum({@N})
```

where N is the field where I calculate the 1s and -1s.

What I've tried so far:

- changed the If test from IsNull to `ToText({Orders.OrderReplacedBy})=""`
- changed the If test to `{Orders.OrderReplacedBy}>0` as the OrderReplacedBy field in the database is numeric and there cannot be values less than zero, so the NULLs should just trigger the Else.
- trid to change the display of the formula to `"1"` and `ToNumber("1")` nothing seems to work

I honestly have no more ideas of what else to try and I also have no knowledge of Crystal Reports (I am only working with it for 2 days and just need to modify a report on an existing app).

Any help would be appreciated,

Thanks :)

P.S.: I am working with Silverlight 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since no one answered I presume that this hasn't happened to anyone or isn't of much interest. But after doing some more research and trying out other stuff I've found a workaroud that I'll post (maybe someone else bumps to this, who knows?):
In the N formula (I don't know why it didn't work the last time I tried) I changed things like this:

```
If IsNull({Orders.OrderReplacedBy})
Then "1"
Else "-1"
```

Added a new formula that isn't used on the report called Numbers

```
If {@N}="1"
Then 1
Else -1
```

And then I changed the sum formula to match the intermediate field

```
Sum({@Numbers})
```

I still don't know the reason why the report didn't want to show me the numbers in the N formula, nor why the sum formula didn't calculate the correct sum.

I hope this is at least going to be useful to someone else,

Cheers!